# Table reservation given the start and end time

Tags: multidimensional-array

Here is a problem that was given to me as part of an online technical screening test on hackerearth. I don't remember the question word to word but will do my best in detailing out the problem

Problem:
Imagine that you own a restaurant. You need to find the number of tables required to accommodate all the reservations. The reservation array consists of start time and end time.
For eg: {{0,10},{5,20}}. So there are 2 reservations. First one starts at time 0 and ends at time 10. Second reservation starts at time 5 and ends at time 20. So in order to accommodate both the reservations we need 2 tables(since both the reservations overlap)

Test Case:
Input: {{5,10},{0,20},{25,40},{35,45}}
Output: 2
Explanation: Table 1 {0,20} {25,40},
Table 2 {5,10} {35,45}

Constraints:

1. Array is not sorted.
2. If the end time of one reservation is the same as the start time of some other reservation then consider that extra table is not required
3. Do not account for a no show scenario

The solution that I came up with looked like this:

1. I first sorted the array as per the start time
2. Then I compared the end time with the next remaining start times. If the end time is greater than the start time then increment the number of tables required.

Here is the code:

```
    int[][] reservationStartEndTimes = {{3,7}, {19,23}, {31,41}, {1,9}, {4,16}};
    Arrays.sort(reservationStartEndTimes, (a,b) -> Integer.compare(a[0], b[0]));
    int tables = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<reservationStartEndTimes.length-1; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<reservationStartEndTimes.length; j++) {
            if(reservationStartEndTimes[i][1] > reservationStartEndTimes[j][0]){
                  tables++;
              }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(tables);
```

However except for the above test case, all the test cases failed for this logic and the other test cases were hidden. I have tried googling the solution but did not find anything useful. Can someone help in understanding what is wrong here and what the correct solution will be?

Answer (score 0):

I also given same problem in one of the coding round on hacker earth. For me also the hidden test cases did not worked. I  had not sorted the array and  i believe that could be the reason.

Here is my code.

```
int[][] reservationStartEndTimes = {{ 0, 20 }, { 25, 40 }, { 5, 10 }, { 35, 25 }};
    List<Integer> tables = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.sort(reservationStartEndTimes, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a[0], b[0]));
    for (int row = 0; row < reservationStartEndTimes.length; row++) {
        int startTime = reservationStartEndTimes[row][0];
        int endTime = reservationStartEndTimes[row][1];
        int time = endTime - startTime;
        boolean reserved = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < tables.size(); i++) {
            if (tables.get(i) < startTime) {
                tables.set(i, tables.get(i) + time);
                reserved = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!reserved)
            tables.add(time);
    }
    System.out.println("Total Table required: "+tables.size());
```